# Выдача данных по критериям

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot

Условие:

- Есть две таблицы - `profile` и `schedule`.
- В таблице `profile` есть три столбца - `course`, `group`, `chat_id`.
- В таблице `scedule` есть два столбца - `course`, `group`.

Задача:

Как выдать "расписание" соответствующее курсу и группе пользователя к курсу и группе "пары".

```
def check_today(self, chat_id):
    with self.conn:
        self.today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM schedule_stom WHERE date = %s AND course = %s AND "group" = %s.............................')
```

Скрины таблиц:

[image: profile]

[image: schedule]

Comment: вас sql - запрос интересует или форматирование строк в python?

Comment: @EugeneDennis Достаточно и SQL запрос. Спасибо

Comment: почитайте как делать запросы к таблицам, а затем про JOIN таблиц по общему полю... если хочется чтоб сделали за вас - задайте вопрос с меткой sql - приведите таблицы-участников и то, что вы хотите увидеть